# Change a href innerHTML without id?

Tags: javascript, href, innerhtml

How do I change texts inside a href's without id's only using javascript?

```
<a href="member.php?action=profile&uid=0">Owner</a>
```

Comment: Are you trying to select the link without using the id attribute or remove the id part of the url inside the href attribute?

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function open_fun() {
    document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = "<a
    href='javascript:oprn()'>CLOSE</a>";
  }
</script>

<body>
<div id='link'><a href='javascript:open()'>OPEN</a></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript method:**

Target the tag and replace the content using *innerHTML*.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML = "New text!";
```

**jQuery method:**

You can directly target the `a` tag to change link text.

```
$('a').html('Hello World');
```

To change the *href* use this:

```
$('a').attr("href", "http://www.google.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="member.php?action=profile&uid=0" onclick="textChanger(this);return false;">Owner</a>

function textChanger(link){
    link.innerHTML = 'YourText';
}
```

It's tested. You can also pass multiple parameters to the function i.e. text/string as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`querySelector()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) method to select the `<a>` tag by its attributes.

**For Example:**

```
var tag = document.querySelector('a[href="member.php?action=profile&uid=0"]');
if(tag){
   tag.innerHTML = "TEXT";
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function update(){
    var tag = document.querySelector('a[href="member.php?action=profile&uid=0"]');
    if(tag){
        tag.innerHTML = "TEXT";
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="member.php?action=profile&uid=0">Owner</a>

<br /><button onclick="update()">Update</button>
```